# Include different JavaScript file depending on browser?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to include a JavaScript file only if the browser is not IE. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are you wanting to use only javascript to do this or are you using a server-side language as well?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update 2022**:

Some options for you:

1. Have your server look at the `User-Agent` header and send different HTML to Internet Explorer vs. other browsers.

   **Pros**:

   - No client-side solution required.

   **Cons**:

   - Relying on `User-Agent` strings is notoriously error-prone, and they can be spoofed or entirely absent.
2. Sniff `navigator.userAgent` and either output a `script` tag or not depending on what you find.

   **Pros:**

   - No server-side requirement.

   **Cons**:

   - Same as #1: Relying on `User-Agent` strings is notoriously error-prone, and they can be spoofed or entirely absent.
   - Some people have an issue with outputting `script` tags from code, particularly via `document.write`, but depending on your use case `document.write` may be unavoidable (e.g., do you need the script there before some other script, etc.).
3. Sniff for something in the JavaScript runtime that only Internet Explorer has, and output a `script` tag or not based on what you find.

   **Pros:**

   - No server-side requirement.
   - No user-agent sniffing.

   **Cons**:

   - The issue some people have with dynamically adding script tags.

I'd probably look at #3. For instance, any even *vaguely* modern browser has the `Symbol` function. Internet Explorer does not. So:

```
if (typeof Symbol !== "undefined") {
    document.write("<script src='./your-non-ie-script.js'><\/script>");
    // Or if you prefer
    let script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "./your-non-ie-script.js";
    document.activeElement.parentNode.appendChild(script);
}
```

`Symbol` is just one example, IE lacks `Reflect`, `Proxy`, and a few others from ES2015 that everything else has now...

*(Not sure why I didn't mention this in 2013!)*

---

**Update 2013**: IE10+ don't support conditional comments anymore.

---

You can do it with IE's [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(VS.85).aspx), like so:

```
<![if !IE]>
<script src="your-non-IE-script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]>
```

Note that the above is processed by non-IE browsers because the conditional is *not* an HTML comment<s>, but a processing instruction,</s> so the bit in the middle is processed by non-IE browsers. IE sees the conditional and skips over the content because it understands the conditional means "Not you, move along."

If you want to do something *only* for IE, you use a form that's similar, but uses HTML comments instead (with the `--`) because that's the only way you can rely on other browsers ignoring the contents. IE knows to pay attention to them, even though they're comments. More on the link above.

Note that there's a page load speed implication on IE (not the other browsers) when you use conditional comments (they temporarily block download of other resources), more here: http://www.phpied.com/conditional-comments-block-downloads/

Comment: I would just like to note that that is not a processing instruction. It's just proprietary Microsoft syntax. A processing instruction is in the form of `<?processing-instruction-name-here ...data here...?>`.

Comment: @Eli: Sure enough (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_Instruction). Wow, I always thought they were processing instructions. Thanks!

Comment: IE 11 loads the your-non-IE-script.js file and throws errors stating ie is undefined.

Comment: @Mike - See the end of the answer: *"**Update 2013**: IE10+ don't support conditional comments anymore."*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I missed the IE10+ update too, please consider to put the update on top of your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an [IE conditional comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(VS.85).aspx).

To get something that will show up in browsers other than IE, but not in IE, and which will still validate, you can use:

```
<!--[if !IE]>-->
  <script src="..."></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 3):

First, a note: This isn't really a good practice. If possible, you should strive to design your website in a browser-agnostic way, so that it works consistently across all browsers without the need to maintain hacks and tricks for browser-specific problems.

But if you really want to do this, it's easiest to include a file only if the browser *is* IE:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="global.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

(Includes the file only if the browser is IE6 or less.)

However, if you really want to do it the other way around, here are some of your options:

1. Use server-side browser sniffing to process the browser before the page is drawn. That is, use a server-side language (Java, PHP, whatever) to determine what the browser is (usually through the user agent string) and then conditionally include your JS files that way. (For example, you can use PHP's [`get_browser`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) function.)
2. Use client-side browser sniffing to call another JS file if the browser is not IE. You can determine the browser using JavaScript itself, and then insert another JS file into the page if the browser is anything but IE. (For example, you can use jQuery's [`browser`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) function.)
3. [T.J.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688769/include-different-javascript-file-depending-on-browser/3688793#3688793) provides a way of doing it with I.E.'s conditional comments as well.

Answer (score 3):

It's lesser known than conditional comments, but I thought I'd mention that you can also use an IE feature called conditional compilation - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kx09ct1%28VS.80%29.aspx

This example comes from their docs:

```
/*@cc_on @*/
/*@if (@_jscript_version >= 5)
document.write("JScript Version 5.0 or better.<BR>");
@else @*/
document.write("You need a more recent script engine.<BR>");
/*@end @*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that totally different way [inserting something ONLY if IE] using Conditional Comments, maybe that would help you.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment

Comment: You can also insert something only when it's *not* IE, using IE's conditional comments. Yes, really.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, conditional scripts for IE is your answer:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]>
  <script src="/js/my_ie_script.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: That will do the quasi-opposite of what the OP asked for.

Comment: Dang, you're correct.  How did I miss the 'not' in the OP's question.  Its late!

Answer (score 0):

How about turning it around? If this is a possibility you can use IE's conditional comments: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Otherwise you could sniff user-agents but this is considered 'bad practice'.

Comment: You don't have to turn it around, IE's conditional comments can be used for targeting non-IE browsers (yes, really).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an solution working in 2022

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>

// Test if running in Internet Explorer or not
function isIE () {
    var myNav = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    return (myNav.indexOf('msie') != -1 || myNav.indexOf('trident') != -1) ? true : false;
}

if (isIE()) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "https://unpkg.com/core-js-bundle@3.6.5/minified.js";
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: User-agent sniffing is well-known to be unreliable, just for what it's worth. It's easily spoofed, etc. (MInd you, spoofers get what they deserve. :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you for updating your solution, it's excellent.