# How to make Asp.net website work both in IE 11 (Non comparability mode ) and IE 8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, cross-browser

We have a website working in IE 8 now and we need to make it work in IE 11 (Non comparability mode). When I make changes to work in IE 11 it is not working  in IE8(JavaScript issue like tag-name giving different value, create srcelement,document.all and many more issues).

I tried creating two java script files one for IE8 and one for IE 11 and loaded based on IE version for couple of pages but seems its not practical.  What is the best way to deal with this type of situation?

Comment: This might be a duplicate. Either way, this post should help you reach your goal.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688769/include-different-javascript-file-depending-on-browser

Comment: I would like to know what are other options other than adding a different javascript file which is a different question.

Answer (score -1):

This will return the IE Browser version else return false. The cool part about basing your logic on choosing which JS file to use is, that you will not have a bunch of IF statements in your JS code like,

```
IF IE11 
 run all this JS code
ELSE IF IE 8 
 run all this JS code
ELSE
 hopefully this JS will work
```

But on the other side of the argument by doing it this way you will not have a ton of JS files with mostly duplicate code in them.

```
function msieversion() {

        var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
        var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

        if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      // If Internet Explorer, return version number
            alert(parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf(".", msie))));
        else                 // If another browser, return 0
            alert('otherbrowser');

   return false;
}
```

Comment: Don't rely on user agents, use feature detection, instead.